# WooCommerce bulk cut white space images

Tags: php, wordpress, image, plugins, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce website with thousands of products, each product is represented by an image.

The images, however, have a lot of white space around the product so I would like to cut the white space to the left and right of the image, wordpress already has the "CUT" feature to crop the image, but having many images.

I would like to find a system to crop the images in bulk giving only the setting to crop 100px to the right and 100px to the left.

---

Example: the images have a resolution of 1000px width and 800px height, I would like to automatically remove 100px on the left and 100px on the right, in this way the image would become 800px * 600px

Comment: If there could be something like: 'this is what I tried, or this is what didn't work, and/or this is what the error is', would have been easy to reply to

Comment: I have found this function wp_get_image_editor() on this page https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Image_Editor , probably this function can help me, but it is not clear to be able to use it with my request

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by Photoshop, LE Version from 10€ or 30 days testversion. You record your steps and then only click "play" ;)